# How was “The Child" found or tracked to the krill farmers?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-mandalorian

In *The Mandalorian*, I suspected that maybe Baby Yoda had a tracking device on him. But there’s no evidence of that. Mando also chose that planet and farm because it’s desolate. So how did that bounty hunter track him?

Comment: The Mandalorian and Cara Dune believe that a Garindan was somehow tracking The Child, but it has yet to be determined how. It's possible the Child has an implant, given he just underwent a procedure (and in ANH a Garindan was an Imperial Informant), but we will have to wait and see how things pan out. Hopefully we will get an answer before season 1 ends.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fgn6kwW2x6Q

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223480/how-do-bounty-hunter-tracking-beacons-work-in-the-mandalorian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tracking fobs are not yet explained in-universe. But the guild uses them to track down the targets. Other targets from the first episode also were tracked with the same device. The Child was also tracked with it in the second episode, before the procedure. I don't think that they are based on an implant - if someone can find the target and implant them, they don't need a bounty hunter to find the target.

They probably work based on DNA to track the target.